# django tutorial02 "playing with the api"

Tags: python, django, api

I have been following the django tutorial perfectly up until the "Playing with the API" point. Now here's my problem. I got to the point where I had to add  `def __str__(self):` to my code.

I did exactly what the tutorial said and when it got to the point that I had to restart the shell, I pressed `ctrl+z` to exit the shell then I started the shell again. The only problem is that when it got to making sure that the `__str__()` addition worked. It didn't. I've been stuck on this for the past week and I really want to move forward. I've looked at everybodys opinion that I've seen and none of the solutions worked.

From my point of view I don't know what I did wrong. Someone help please. I'm using python 3.9.2. The only place I'm not sure of was the restarting of the shell.

Comment: Ctrl+Z does not exit the current task: https://superuser.com/a/476875/938297

Comment: well, I'd also quote "Control+Z is used for suspending a process [cut]. While Control+C is used to kill a process [cut].". https://superuser.com/questions/262942/

Comment: Okay thank you . How do you propose I exit the shell? By pressing ctrl +c ?